Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source
After I installed postgresql, i have errors:
E: Des valeurs entrant en conflit ont été renseignées pour l'option Signed-By à propos de la source https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ noble-pgdg: /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.asc != /usr/share/postgresql-common/pgdg/apt.postgresql.org.gpg
E: La liste des sources ne peut être lue.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04
